# Why does react-native webview load page super zoomed out?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-webview

Im loading a page in a webview in a react-native app. the html for this page is rendered/sent by the server to the client. testing this server endpoint with my desktop browser as the client, it looks great, works great, no issues.

When I navigate to the same server endpoint in a webview, the page is super zoomed out, the buttons, inputs, text, etc are all really small. Im not looking for the user to be able to zoom in, I just want the page to load as it does in the browser when the browsers width is 375px.

here's the webview:

```
<WebView
    style={{ height: height, width: width }}
    ref={(ref) => (this.webview = ref)}
    source={{ uri: API_ENDPOINT }}
    renderError={(error) => <View style={{ flex: 1 }}><Text>{error}</Text></View>}
    onError={syntheticEvent => {
        const { nativeEvent } = syntheticEvent;
        console.warn('WebView error: ', nativeEvent);
    }}
    startInLoadingState={true}
    renderLoading={() => <ActivityIndicator size={"large"} color={Colors.PRIMARY_GREEN} />}
    scalesPageToFit={false}
/>
```

Why is this happening and how can this be mitigated?

Edit: I noticed if I change size values to "vw" "vh", it will respond correctly. does this have something to do with how react-native handles size values or density independent pixels?

Comment: Different systemwide font-size settings?

Comment: @Dai yes obviously I could just make everything bigger. but that just doesn't seem right. for instance, once of the elements is set to be 275px wide. simulator is something like 375px wide. shouldn't have to do that